# Next.js: How to start the development mode with CLI (next dev) over https localhost

Tags: next.js

in Next.js, wow to start the development mode with CLI (next dev) over https localhost?

What parameters should I pass to "next dev" command, which can be edited in package.json?

I don't want to write the custom https server for development.

Thank you.

Comment: Use ngrok, very easy to use tool to make local port available online via https. Method explained here: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/run-next-js-app-locally-in-https/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edit: January 2024 - It looks like there’s an experimental flag that supports local HTTPS development! https://x.com/leeerob/status/1743709145386131906?s=46&t=0R3aF2_pSTqUMFxVSB7eLQ

———

Old Answer:

This might not help you if you're trying to do local development with the Facebook API, but there's a discussion comment in the Next.js repo which suggests that you can use [local-ssl-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ssl-proxy) to do SSL local dev.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10935#discussioncomment-144885

Comment: It's nice!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily have an https dev server by using ngrok:
follow these simple steps:

1. Create a free ngrok account.
2. Install ngrok client based on your system (`yay -S ngrok`  for arch based linux)
3. Setup your config using your [ngrok authen Key](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken).
   `ngrok config add-token 'authen-key'`
4. Run your Nextjs Server
5. Run `ngrok http 3000` or your preferred port

[image]

go to the ngrok link and enjoy !